# Passing in window into IIFE and other dependencies also from window

Tags: javascript, oop, dependencies, iife

Why do some programmers pass in the global `window` object, which I understand is for better performance and minifying benefits, but also other dependency objects / functions from the exact same global space `window` but passed in through another parameter?

But then they also use functions from `window` that they don't pass in explicitly, like `setTimeout()`.

```
(function (dependency1, dependency2, dependency3, dependency4) {
    'use strict';

    //body

    window.setTimeout(function() { // <--
        //body
    }, 1000);

    //etc.
}(window, window.document, window.AjaxRequest, window.util.padNumber)); // <--
```

Are there any benefits to using the top variant over the following, which basically still has access to the same dependencies?

```
(function (window) {
    'use strict';

    //body

    window.setTimeout(function() {
        //body
    }, 1000);

    //etc.
}(window));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The interpreter does not have to traverse up the scope to find the dependencies, they are just available in the current scope.
2. Location/Namespaces of dependencies may change in future, but if you pass them in as parameters you just have to change the passed parameters, not all occurrences in your code.
3. Minification, local variables are safe to be renamed

Comment: But let's say I use the native available objects / functions from JS that reside in `window`, like `Date()`, `setTimeout()`, `clearInterval()` and `Array()`. Most of the time I see programmers only pass in `window` to the IIFE. Why? Wouldn't it then be better to pass in all of those dependency objects / function explicitly into the IIFE as well?

Comment: Generally you're right. I would say most of the time it is `(window, document)`. This is just because mostly this objects get accessed many times, for DOM manipulation, etc.. You will see many times too, that someone passes in his favorite library, because it gets accessed many times too, like jQuery: `(window, document, window.jQuery)` Of course you could pass in `window.Date`, but how often do you access it? One or two times? So maybe you optimize the scope lookup a bit, but create a minimal longer download time, because of more chars in your code. So find a balance ;)

Comment: So basically if I for example have a function that can send AJAX requests, but I only use it one time in the code, I do not really have to pass it into the IIFE because that would be considered micro optimization?

Answer (score 1):

This is done in order to stick to OPEN/CLOSE paradigm.

> the open/closed principle states "software entities (classes, modules,
>   functions, etc.) should be open for extension, but closed for
>   modification"

To close the modification, you pass the dependencies as parameter. This allows a programmer to change it on the fly without worrying about no of places it is being used in the function.